# How to retrieve a certain field value in HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html

I'm not very familiar in HTML and I don't know quite well how to manipulate it, what I have is the following:

```
<td class="FieldName">Ingredients:</td><td>Biotin
  - 0.25mg, Calcium (phosphate, pantothenate) - 100mg, Copper (sulfate) -
 1mg, Dexpanthenol - 10mg, Folic acid - 1mg, Iron (carbonate, sulfate, 
elemental) - 10mg, Magnesium (phosphate, stearate, oxide) - 5mg, 
Manganese (sulfate) - 0.5mg, Molybdenum (molybdate) - 0.1mg, 
Nicotinamide - 50mg, Phosphorus (phosphate - 84mg, Vitamin A - 3333IU, 
Vitamin B1 - 20mg, Vitamin B2 - 5mg, Vitamin B6 - 10mg, Vitamin C - 
150mg , Vitamin D2 - 1000IU, Vitamin E, - 10mg, Vitamine B12 - 5mcg, 
Zinc (sulfate) - 0.5mg</td>
```

I want to retrieve the value associated with "Ingredients:", so how can I accomplish it?

Comment: You might want to retrieve the `<tr>` tag that surrounds all of the `<td>` tags you metioned above

Comment: html can not manipulate itself... do you want to manipulate it using javascript?

Comment: Please change tag if you want javascript solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use jsoup library

```
public void getData() throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("path/to/html/file"), "UTF-8"); //You can parse a url also instead of file

    String text = "";
    Elements e = doc.select("td.FieldName + td");
    for (Element temp : e) {            
        text = temp.text();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the id to <td> element like <td id="Ingredients"> and then use below to get the value using javascript:-

```
var ingredientVal = (document.getElementById("Ingredients")).innerHTML;
```

Comment: What if there are more rows with data, and OP can't change HTML structure? However, still not sure is this java or javascript question... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to retrive info in html.
XPath is (maybe) javascript language that takes object in your HTML and after that you can read/write datas.
You can try it simply using your browser console(In chrome [CTRL + F12] or [right click on page -> inspect element -> console tab]).

You can learn a lot here (This is the syntax section, you can browse around the section): 
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

If you want to try it in you page, try: "$x("//td[@class='FieldName']/text()");"

---

Quick reference:

$x(""); :: Method supported by Chrome and FF to execute xPaths(You will find online the correct method for your programming languages);

//  :: Means "Search in the page or in the child you are in";

td  :: Means "Returns all the td tags";

[@class='FieldName'] :: Means "Filter by class" (You can also filter by id, name.. etc.);

/ :: Means "Go into the object and do something else." (In this case I retrive the text, but you can go deeper in the structure, like "/td/div/td[@class...]/td and so on");

text() :: retrive the text;

Hope this helps,
Andrea.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```
var maintd = document.getElementsByClassName("FieldName");
var childtd = maintd.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
```